# Aurelia EventAggregator does not import correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I followed the tutorial http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial/1

Everthing looks fine. But after I import EventAggregator (import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';), aurelia does not load it correctly. It is loaded from folder dist (compile js folder) instead of jspm_packages.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably didnt run `jspm install aurelia-event-aggregator`. Run that and you should be back in business.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I see aggregator in this  
"npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@1.0.0": { "aurelia-event-aggregator": "npm:aurelia-event-aggregator@1.0.0" .. }. So I thought I should not need to install another aggreator

Comment: Well, if you're using the Aurelia cli, then you won't be using jspm. Are you using the cli or are you using a jspm based guide?

Comment: I don't use cli to create new Aurelia project. I use existing skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore with some modification to adapt for my project

Comment: Gotcha. This comment must be 15 chars long

Comment: Back in the family bidness.